# update another viewController UI from a UIPopoverController button iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I have a mapView that has a popover that is presented when the right navbar button is pressed. In this popover I have 2 buttons that call 2 methods in the mapView. I have hooked up the code and when the buttons are pressed I can see in the Log that they are being called from the popover (The 2 methods in the map view) however these buttons control the refreshing of my map or re-entering it to the users location.

The issue I have is the methods are called but the mapView doesn't update as expected however calling the same methods from the mapView directly it works and the UI updates??

Does a popover block UI changes in other controllers while present? Or am I fundamentally not getting something?

The recenter map method looks like the below for example:

```
-(void)recenterMap{
NSLog(@"Recenter map");
[recycleMap setCenterCoordinate:recycleMap.userLocation.location.coordinate   animated:YES];
}
```

As mentioned when calling this method from the popover I can see that it logs it but never does anything as mentioned with the UI however directly it does from the mapView as a test?

calling method from popover like this:

```
-(IBAction)recenterTheMap:(id)sender{

//incidentsMapView is the mapView and recenterMap is the method in that class to recenter it
[self.incidentsMapView recenterMap];
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the recenterMap method from the pop-over view controller?

Comment: @StePrescott I have added it with comments to my question at the bottom. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with blocks or delegates?

Comment: @StePrescott i did read up on protocols but couldnt get it to work..so i am guessing fundamentally i can't expect my code above to work

Answer (score 0):

```
[recycleMap setCenterCoordinate:recycleMap.userLocation.location.coordinate   animated:YES];
```

should be

```
[self.recycleMap setCenterCoordinate:recycleMap.userLocation.location.coordinate   animated:YES];
```

XCode should be throwing a warning about your omission of `self.`